# String line limit?

Tags: java, string

I am writing a method that will read from a text file and tell how many people in that text file are born within the years 1920 to 1984 inclusive, but for some reason it will only ever store a maximum of 45 lines.

```
private Buffin itsFile = new Buffin("workers.txt");
private static final int TIME_SPAN = 65;
private static final int YEAR = 1920;

public String countBirthYears()
{
    try
    {
        int[] count = new int[TIME_SPAN];

        //== READ THE WORKER DATA AND UPDATE THE COUNTS
        Worker data = new Worker(itsFile.readLine());
        while(data.getName() != null)
        {
            if((data.getBirthYear() - YEAR) >= 0 && (data.getBirthYear() - YEAR) <= 1984){
                int lastDigit = data.getBirthYear() % 10;
                count[lastDigit]++;
            }

            data = new Worker(itsFile.readLine());
        }

        //== CONSTRUCT THE STRING OF ANSWERS
        String s = "";
        for(int k = 0; k < TIME_SPAN; k++)
            s += (YEAR + k) + " : " + count[k] + " workers\n";
        return s;
    }catch(Exception e){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e); return "";}
}
```

I would appreciate if someone could explain to me as to why this is happening and how to fix it. thanks :)

Comment: Have you verified that `count` contains the correct number of entries? Also, that if you print the lines one by one the correct count is printed?

Comment: Did you debug and print value of s return by the method

Comment: Yeah I had it print s everytime it went through the loop and it worked correctly. I am not sure why it doesn't when just using the method though.

Comment: So you facing issue in this method or while writing in any file ?

Comment: Does running the code generate an *exception* at all? Or what indicates that it "only ever store a maximum of 45 lines"? (I believe there is a logic bug - there is at least one with the modulus, where it will never write past count[9] - not related to a "limit".)

Comment: I don't get any exceptions it runs completely fine :/ I don't know what is causing the problem but it is problem something stupid I'm sure lol

Comment: @IanLundberg So you're *not* hitting a "limit", and the two current answers are irrelevant. This is why a good title - one that *doesn't* suppose an issue - can make a *huge* difference. Because, even if there *is* a limit (and there is), it's simply not relevant here.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what the title should be though?

Comment: Can you add one sysout after addition of string to s.

Comment: I don't see the "lines" in the code, what is meant by "store a maximum of 45 lines"? I see `count` which is an array of 65 integers (of which only the first 10 indices are filled).

Comment: @user2864740 when I print the string it is supposed to print a line for every year starting from 1920 to 1984 with the number of workers from those years which would be 65 lines, whereas it only prints 45

Comment: @IanLundberg That's not possible. It will throw an exception or print `TIME_SPAN` lines (rather, the string will have at least `TIME_SPAN` "\n" characters in it). Perhaps the *display* only shows 45 lines?

Comment: The for loop adds a new line to the String everytime until k is equal to 65, but it only seems to add 45 lines.

Comment: It could be the display I never even really thought about that

Comment: @IanLundberg If the loop runs 65 times, it runs 65 times. In that case, it's probable that something else is removing the extra 20 lines or otherwise failing to display them. You can replace the code in the loop with a `println` to feel good about 65 lines.

Comment: I don't know what is causing it to fail displaying them though there is no option in my compiler to increase the limit of the display

Comment: @IanLundberg The terminal size is not controlled by the compiler. You *are* writing it to the terminal? (That is, where/how is countBirthYears used?)

Comment: Okay I found the option for unlimited buffering and that fixed the issue I knew it would be something stupid

Comment: @IanLundberg Hurrah! Glad the problem is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not a real answer actually but I would like to address a couple of things in your code and I hope it can help you:

1.

```
if((data.getBirthYear() - YEAR) >= 0 && (data.getBirthYear() - YEAR) <= 1984)
```

Does not actually check for birthYears within 1920 and 1984, but it includes all the years between 1920 and 3904

I think you meant:

```
if((data.getBirthYear() - YEAR) >= 0 && (data.getBirthYear() - YEAR) <= TIME_SPAN)
```

2.

```
int lastDigit = data.getBirthYear() % 10;
count[lastDigit]++;
```

Actually adds up people born in 1973 and those born in 1983 (for instance)... is this what you really want?

Maybe the problem is not in String limits but there might be something in the logic...

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing these out I just drew up the code quick haven't really checked over anything yet, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The size of the String is limited in Java. The amount of chars the String object can hold is actually equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If you are exceeding this lenght you should consider using `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder` to create your output based on if you work with it in different threads (StringBuffer is synchronized).

You can use

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for(int k = 0; k < TIME_SPAN; k++)
        s.append(YEAR + k).append(" : ").append(count[k]).append(" workers\n");

return sb; //sb.toString();
```

Note: If you have a small heap size you may be even more limited. The String maximum
length is either `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or half your heap size, whichever is smaller.

Comment: I doubt he's running into a hard-limit; surely if the code was there would be an exception or something..

Comment: I still run into the same problem when running the method using a StringBuilder I just tried :/

This is what the output looks like http://gyazo.com/0425623a17955fc512cd0f2875f3de7b

Answer (score -1):

Yes, string is limited. As far as I remember the limit depends on JVM and is something like 64K.

But it even does not matter. You do not have to read whole file into one string to detect how many people match your criteria. Even if there is no limitation on string size. What if your file contains list of all 7 billion people? Do you want to hold in memory the whole list just to return a simple counter in the end of your run?

You have to read your file line-by-line, parse each line and increment your counter if it is needed. No need to store the whole information in RAM.

Comment: @user2864740, may be 640. It really does not matter. The catch is that OP is reading whole file into RAM.

Comment: Reading the entire file into memory doesn't sound that bad either; at least not inherently so, even if it's not ideal. (The entire Shakespeare collection is supposed to only be like 5.5MB; and even if it were 550MB, well, it's only half a GB ..)

Comment: @user2864740, it does not matter how Shakespeare collection is big. What *does* matter is that there is no reason to read whole data from disk into RAM just to generate a simple counter that can be found when reading the data incrementally.

Comment: What matters *here* is reading the actual question, not just the title. (The code actually does the "proposed solution", just with a messy re-build up of the output at the end.)

Comment: I have indeed read the question. The problem is that the code reads only first 45 line. I tried to explain that the code as it is written is wrong conceptually. If for example user is lucky enough using small files or using `StringBuilder` and so on this code can work. He will continue writing code using this IMHO wrong pattern and will meet problems later. I just wanted to avoid this in the beginning.

Comment: This answer is wrong in context. If there *was* a hard-limit being reached, then an Exception (i.e. an OutOfMemoryError) would have been thrown. This is not the case. Since the final loop *must* loop TIME_SPAN (65) times and thus *must* include at least 65 "\n" characters and 65 lines, then the issue - which was identified by the OP and has nothing to do with string/line limits - is that the output is not being used correctly. In this particular case it was terminal scrolling.